# Magento module works well on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, magento

I have a weird case here....

I'm making a simple magento module right now. Some kind of script injection module (similar to google analytics module). I've built the admin config for that module (which is defined from `system.xml`)
[image]

as seen on the image. This module works very well on my localhost. But it's getting weird on the live server. The modules looks like it doesn't enabled at all although I have totally make sure it's all already enabled. Both via magento admin area and also via `app/etc/modules`. That admin config area never appear on live server's magento installation.

does anybody know what's the issue with this problem?
or at least tell me how and where should I debug it? I've been digging it to magento core code but getting stuck on getSingleton() function somewhere around magento core code. I don't understand that way-too-MVC stuff :p

I would be very glad if someone could explain and guide me on this

thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common problems are associated with case sensitivity. If you have Windows hosting, then the error in the uppercase/lowercase characters is not visible and it works. But as soon as it gets to linux hosting, the module will not work.

Check the paths in the settings and folders/files - so that they match.

Comment: thanks a lot Юрий, I found it just one tiny little "m" character that makes it all wrong :D

Comment: Been searching for days and this is the answer that helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

Usually there are three things:

- typos in xml files (validate them with validator)
- cache is not cleared after installation (clear cache)
- ACL rules are not reinitiated (re-save admin roles)

Answer (score 0):

**If you adjust the layout/add your own layout in the backoffice of magento, it's best to clear the cache (remove everything in the var/cache/ folder) and to logout and re-login.**

Answer (score 0):

Thumb rules while deploying magento custom module on the live server-

1. Deploy your custom module
2. Flush your all magento cache or at-least refresh them
   [System->Cache Management]
3. If you have enabled compilation re-run the compilation or disable compilation until the testing is done.
   [System-Tools->Compilation]

Comment: This solves the **bold**Network Error: 500 Internal Server Error**bold** also, when deploying your module stops the functionality of entire website including the admin area.